# How to set up messaging subsystem using CLI in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

Does anyone have an example script for setting up the messaging subsystem in Wildfly using CLI?

The perfect example would be the CLI needed to take a server running the standalone.xml, and after running the CLI script it has the messaging subsystem as defined in the standalone-full.xml.

The examples I've found so far all start with the assumption the messaging subsystem is already in place.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use standalone-full.xml?

Comment: Because standalone-full.xml has everything in it.  We're trying to automate the deployment process, and we'd like to keep it to running just what we need.

Comment: Fair enough. So you could start with `/extension=org.jboss.as.messaging:add(module=org.jboss.as.messaging)` then `/subsystem=messaging:add`. That will give you the base subsystem with defaults.

Comment: I'm not sure all the defaults you want, it will exist :)

Comment: That helps me get started.  I've also was pointed to http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.1.0.Final/subsystem/messaging/index.html  If I get the final script running, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the script to add messaging.  This adds the messaging subsystem, and makes it look like the subsystem when running standalone-full.xml.

```
/extension=org.jboss.as.messaging:add()
batch
/subsystem=messaging:add
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:add
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/:write-attribute(name=journal-file-size, value=102400L)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/address-setting=#:add(address-full-policy="PAGE", \
    dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ", expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue", expiry-delay=-1L, \
    last-value-queue=false, max-delivery-attempts=10, max-size-bytes=10485760L, message-counter-history-day-limit=10, \
    page-max-cache-size=5, page-size-bytes=2097152L, redelivery-delay=0L, redistribution-delay=-1L, send-to-dla-on-no-route=false)

/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/in-vm-connector=in-vm:add(server-id=0)
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/in-vm-acceptor=in-vm:add(server-id=0)

/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/http-connector=http-connector:add(socket-binding="http", param={http-upgrade-endpoint="http-acceptor"})
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/http-connector=http-connector-throughput:add(socket-binding="http", param={http-upgrade-endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput", batch-delay=50})
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor:add(http-listener="default")
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor-throughput:add(http-listener="default", param={batch-delay=50, direct-deliver=false})

/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/connection-factory=InVmConnectionFactory:add(connector={"in-vm"=>undefined}, entries = ["java:/ConnectionFactory"])
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/connection-factory=RemoteConnectionFactory:add(connector={"http-connector"=>undefined}, entries = ["java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"])

/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/pooled-connection-factory=hornetq-ra:add(connector={"in-vm"=>undefined}, entries=["java:/JmsXA","java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"])
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/security-setting=#:add()
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/security-setting=#/role=guest:add(consume=true, create-durable-queue=false, create-non-durable-queue=true, delete-durable-queue=false, delete-non-durable-queue=true, manage=false, send=true)

jms-queue add --queue-address=ExpiryQueue --durable=true --entries=["java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"] 
jms-queue add --queue-address=DLQ --durable=true --entries=["java:/jms/queue/DLQ"]
run-batch
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is an updated CLI command for new Wildfly 10 (**ActiveMQ Artemis**)

>> ADD MESSAGING SUBSYSTEM

```
/extension=org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq:add()
/subsystem=messaging-activemq:add
/:reload
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:add
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/security-setting=#:add
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/address-setting=#:add(dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ", expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue", expiry-delay="-1L", max-delivery-attempts="10", max-size-bytes="10485760", page-size-bytes="2097152", message-counter-history-day-limit="10")
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-connector=http-connector:add(socket-binding="http", endpoint="http-acceptor")
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-connector=http-connector-throughput:add(socket-binding="http", endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" ,params={batch-delay="50"})
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-connector=in-vm:add(server-id="0")
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor:add(http-listener="default")
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor-throughput:add(http-listener="default", params={batch-delay="50", direct-deliver="false"})
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-acceptor=in-vm:add(server-id="0")
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=ExpiryQueue:add(entries=["java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"])
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=DLQ:add(entries=["java:/jms/queue/DLQ"])
```

>> Refresh needed at this point

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/connection-factory=InVmConnectionFactory:add(connectors=["in-vm"], entries=["java:/ConnectionFactory"])
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/connection-factory=RemoteConnectionFactory:add(connectors=["http-connector"], entries = ["java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"])
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/pooled-connection-factory=activemq-ra:add(transaction="xa", connectors=["in-vm"], entries=["java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"])
/subsystem=ee/service=default-bindings/:write-attribute(name="jms-connection-factory", value="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
/subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-resource-adapter-name", value="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}")
/subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-mdb-instance-pool", value="mdb-strict-max-pool")
```

>> ADD MESSAGE QUEUE

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=MyQueue:add(entries=[java:/jms/queue/MyQueue])
```

All commands may be ran as a batch command or separately like this:

```
$SERVER_CLI_PATH --connect --user=$SERVER_USER --password=$SERVER_PASSW --command="{{line with command}}"
```

Answer (score 5):

To set up messaging in WildFly 14, I had to do the configuration with separate CLI script files, otherwise `jboss-cli` would fail with `JBTHR00004: Operation was cancelled` exceptions, probably due to incomplete reloads. In case you still encounter these errors, add `sleep` commands in between to the shell script that runs the CLI scripts.

1. Add the messaging extension, `1-add-messaging-extension-and-subsystem.cli`:

   ```
   batch

   # Add messaging extension
   /extension=org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq:add()

   # Add messaging subsystem
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq:add

   run-batch

   /:reload
   ```
2. Add the messaging server **allowing only in-VM connectors**, `2-add-messaging-server.cli`:

   ```
   batch

   # Add messaging server with default configuration, allow only in-VM connectors
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:add
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/security-setting=#:add
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/address-setting=#:add( \
           dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ", \
           expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue", \
           max-size-bytes="10485760", \
           message-counter-history-day-limit="10", \
           page-size-bytes="2097152")
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-connector=in-vm:add( \
           server-id="0",params=buffer-pooling=false)
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-acceptor=in-vm:add( \
           server-id="0",params=buffer-pooling=false)
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=ExpiryQueue:add( \
           entries=["java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"])
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=DLQ:add( \
           entries=["java:/jms/queue/DLQ"])
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/connection-factory=InVmConnectionFactory:add( \
           connectors=["in-vm"], \
           entries=["java:/ConnectionFactory"])
   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/pooled-connection-factory=activemq-ra:add( \
           transaction="xa", \
           connectors=["in-vm"], \
           entries=["java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"])

   # Configure default connection factory in the EE subsystem
   /subsystem=ee/service=default-bindings/:write-attribute(name="jms-connection-factory", value="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")

   # Configure message-driven beans in the EJB subsystem
   /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-resource-adapter-name", value="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}")
   /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-mdb-instance-pool", value="mdb-strict-max-pool")

   run-batch

   /:reload
   ```

In case you need HTTP connectors as well, see @petr-hunka's answer.